# Is there any limit for number of items sent in HTML form?

Tags: paypal

We have an order with 112 items and proper HTML form for it:

```
<form id="paypal_cart_upload" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Red lace knitted dress for girls" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="233.64" />
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="tax_1" value="58.41" />
    .......
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_112" value="Green lace knitted dress for girls" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_112" value="233.64" />
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity_112" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="tax_112" value="58.41" />

    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="handling_cart" value="6.47" />
    <input type="hidden" name="tax_cart" value="7423.07" />
    <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="1466503094" />
```

But in fact after redirect on paypal website I see only 99 items.

Answer (score 0):

It used to be a 99 item limit but thing have changed in the last few months and the limit is down to around 11 or 12 it seems, or it could be the amount of data you POST to PayPal. See [PayPal HTML buttons broken for large shopping carts on new PayPal checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39579710/paypal-html-buttons-broken-for-large-shopping-carts-on-new-paypal-checkout)

Comment: could you please bring the necessary portion of the link here?